# Determine Client's Computer Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an intranet site that will display different lists based on the computer name because different computers are in different areas, is there a way (within a controller or model) to determine the client's computer name?

I have tried system.environment.machinename but that only returns the name of the server, any other ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got it working using the following:

```
string IP = Request.UserHostName;
string compName = CompNameHelper.DetermineCompName(IP);
```

code from compnamehelper:

```
public static string DetermineCompName(string IP)
{
    IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
    IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
    List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
    return compName.First();
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not give you the expected result if the client is behind a NAT, but chances are that it's not a problem since you're on an "intranet".

Comment: It is working like a charm. But small change i had to make for getting the IP. string ip = HttpContext.Request.UserHostName.ToString(); rest are  awesomely working.. +1

Comment: Well, it may work only on local area network but it will not work on the internet.

Comment: I just get this error "no such host is known" on the *Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP)*, is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

code in VB :

```
Dim myIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Request.UserHostName)
    Dim GetIPHost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP)
    Dim compName As List(Of String) = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString.Split("").ToList

    return(compName.First)
```

Answer (score 3):

No. The client's computer name is not available in any way on the server. This is the nature of the http request-response. You only can have its IP address.

A workarounds could be to retrieve machine on the client from Flash/Silverlight (I doubt JavaScript) and put in into cookie which is available on the server with each request. But there is a whole stack of issues with this approach.

Comment: is there a method to lookup computer names with an ip?

Comment: You can get computer name from its IP by making a call to DNS server

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off using one of these methods to tie a user to a location:

- a cookie that is set once the user self-selects their location
- having the user login to the site so that you can track them uniquely that way
- remembering user by IP address

There is no way of ensuring remote hostnames are unique. The same issue occurs with IP because of proxies, dynamic IP, etc., but I think it will be a little more reliable. Also, you can do geolocation by IP address.

Comment: I have a similar need to know if a user is on a "certain" PC or not...and I believe a cookie is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string name = Request.UserHostName;
```

Comment: Didn't work, returned name of web server. Same with System.Net.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to inspect the client is through the ServerVariables collection on the Request object (should be available for MVC code).

See https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201638/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092298-3.shtml for more information.  REMOTE_HOST and REMOTE_ADDR look like candidates.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an IE-only solution. It works in IE8, with multiple security warnings.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var ax = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
   document.write(ax.UserName + '<br />'); //logged in account name
   document.write(ax.ComputerName + '<br />'); //Windows PC name
</script>
```