# Get host name in webapi method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to get website url into my webapi method.
e.g
my website name is abc.com and my api method url is xyz.com/getdetails?a=1
now on my webapi controller i want to get abc.com url to identify from this method was called.

Comment: do you want the IP address of client calling you API?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi i want domain name of the client.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445109/3621001)

Answer (score 5):

You get some complete information along with port on which the api is hosted. But you will need to add System.Web to make it work.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need the referring URL for that.

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Comment: it always give null value.

Comment: Works for me. I make a request to my api from a jsfiddle demo. My urlReferrer comes back with: https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ 
What does your code look like? Sounds to me like you're accessing the property before making an api request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Web;`.

Comment: i have try this but it always gives me webapi hostaddress or hostname

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using OWIN, then

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

That's in the `System.Web` namespace

If you're using OWIN and you're **not** using the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` nuget package that provides classic asp.net `HttpContext`, you can also get it from OWIN context like this:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Host.Value
```

The GetOwinContext extension function is provided by the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin nuget package.