# can't get computer name of client user visit and run my web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

Suppose I work on ASP.NET MVC web application and this application hosted on IIS so I need to get computer name of user visit my web application

As example client A have computer-001 he visit web application then get computer name computer-001 and display it on application .

computer B

have computer name computer-002 then register computer name computer-002 on web application using asp.net mvc

So exactly I need to get computer name that visit web application

Ruby

Copy

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAuditLog()
{
    string computername = //get computer visit my web application who run my app
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444592/126014

Comment: You can't know, get, or steal ANYTHING from my computer. You can't know what folders I have, and you can't get my computer name.  Such information is not exposed to the browser, and thus you can't know if I'm using a iPad, an Android phone, or a windows computer. So, what computer name you going to get when I visit your site with a iPad? It really does not matter, since such information about the computer is not exposed to the web browser, and thus you can't get that information's anyway. You can in some cases get such information if you using Active Directory logons on a intera-net.